# looking for an angular code gallery suitable for copy paste

Tags: angular

I am learning Angular 4 and starting to build my 1st application.

I use Angular CLI for scaffolding the code. Also, I use a few sample applications (such as hero app) for copy and paste code, then modify it to my application need.

The problem is that the sample apps I am copying from are small and limited. There are significant API calls and syntax involved with Angular. I know the big picture, but there are lots of detail involved, one type mistake might become hard to debug.

Is there any angular gallery available so I can copy/paste an Angular code for common scenarios, then modify the pasted code to my application need?

I am looking for something like blow bootstrap code sample gallery for angular

http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: https://medium.com/aviabird/10-amazing-open-source-angular-2-x-apps-825fb169dce3 ?

Comment: Do you mean small example apps or something related to showcase of custom components? The second would be more of a documentation/example page of a css framework like material

Comment: @Jota.Toledo, thank you for help. the sample apps help. I was more looking for a code gallery style similar to what we have in http://getbootstrap.com/css/ that works well for me. I look for what I need on a page, copy/paste then change.

Comment: that depends on the css framework(s) and modules that you want to use, lol

Comment: @Jota.Toledo, not the CSS code. I like to copy/paste Angular Forms, Pipes, Routes etc.Are https://angular.io samples my only choice?